# Why emma doesn't give full coverage to finally blocks?

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma

I don't get why emma doesn't give full code coverage to "finally" blocks. I've made a short example program to demonstrate this.

When I execute the program it shows:

```
try
finally
```

So I don't get why finally is marked as red (not executed) and the "finally" "println" is marked yellow (partially executed). Am I missing something? How to make emma understand that the finally block is covered?

[image: example]

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an entry on this in the EMMA Faq: [Implicit branches due to finally blocks.](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) touching on the subject of partially covered finally blocks. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: Thank you! In fact executing the code with and without exception inside the try block gives full coverage to the finally block.

Comment: @stivlo Can you explain more?

Comment: @JPM The reason is written in the link provided by aioobe: *The compiler must ensure that the cleanup code [the finally block] is always executed, whether or not there is an exception thrown in the try block. There are thus two possible paths leading into the finally block: with and without an exception pending.*