# finally block doesn't marked as passed throught in intellij coverage

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I Have a piece of a really simple code.

Something like:

```
public class Foo {
   public void bar() {
      timer.start();
      try{
        ///
      } finally {
         timer.stop();
      }
   }
}
```

I have a unit test that runs with Mockito and when I use IntelliJ option for code-coverage it marks the line in the `finally` as not covered. The thing is that it happens only when I throw an exception inside the `try`. The even more weird issue is that I have an assert that makes sure the call in the `finally` block was called:

```
Mockito.verify(timer).stop(); // timer is mocked here of course
```

When I run debug, the debugger stops in this line.
When I run a test without an exception in the `finally` block - the coverage marks it as covered.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you verifying `bar`? How does `Foo` (or `bar()`) have visibility to `timer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why emma doesn't give full coverage to finally blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841882/why-emma-doesnt-give-full-coverage-to-finally-blocks)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I didn't write the whole code here but timer is an injected mock object. It's injected in the constructor. In the test I mock it in order to run `verify` on it.